# How to use a WriteStream in Gridfs Stream

Tags: node.js

What is a Writestream in gridfs-stream and what does it do? Also what is the path that is needed to create a read stream out of a write stream

```
var writestream = gfs.createWriteStream({
      filename: 'my_file.txt'
});
fs.createReadStream('/some/path').pipe(writestream);

// streaming from gridfs
var readstream = gfs.createReadStream({
filename: 'my_file.txt'
});

//error handling, e.g. file does not exist
readstream.on('error', function (err) {
console.log('An error occurred!', err);
throw err;
});

readstream.pipe(response);
```